# Field in the model does not change in django app

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm working on a django 1.4.5. I added to the model, select the size of T-shirts.

**Field in my model**

```
tshirt_size = models.CharField(choices=TSHIRT_SIZE_CHOICES, default="s", blank=True, null=True, max_length=24)
```

**My form**

```
class SubscriberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Subscriber
        exclude = ['event', 'is_active']
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(),
            'last_name': TextInput(),
            'email': TextInput(),
            'tshirt_size': Select(choices=TSHIRT_SIZE_CHOICES)
        }
```

In view, I get data in this way:

```
tshirt_size = request.POST.get('tshirt_size')
```

**Part of html code**

```
<label for="id_tshirt_size">T-Shirt Size (Unisex):</label>
{{ form.tshirt_size }}
```

And when I execute save on form I get in admin panel None value for tshirt_size.

Comment: Why are you looking up `request.POST.get('tshirt_size')` in your view when you're using a `ModelForm` ? It's the form's job to take care of it.  Looks like you're not using the `ModelForm` correctly.

Comment: If I delete this part from my view: `tshirt_size = request.POST.get('tshirt_size')` I get always size "S" (default) evan when I choose "L" size for example @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: you're obviously NOT using your form the right way. It's a ModelForm, it knows how to get data from the request, validate them, and create/update your model instance. You __dont__ have to do this manually in the view code (which you didn't post FWIW), just use the form as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the canonical way to use a ModelForm to create or update a model instance:

```
def myview(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Subscriber, pk=pk)
    else:
        instance = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubscriberForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            # do whatever with instance or just ignore it
            return redirect(some return url)
    else:
        form = SubscriberForm(instance=instance)
    context = {"form":form}
    return render(request, "path/to/your/template.html", context)
```

If your view doesn't look something like it then you're very probably doing it wrong. Your mention of a `tshirt_size = request.POST.get('tshirt_size')` in your view is a sure smell you're doing it wrong FWIW.

Comment: I have other fields in my view, which are collected in this way and work. Here is a select and view is None.

Comment: @mark since you didn't post all the relevant code (one line of a model, one line of a view, two lines of a template...), there's no way to know what _else_ is wrong with your code.  But really, start with using Django the right way, it will save you a __lot__ of time, problems, security issues and headaches.